# Implicit Conversion from tuple to custom type parameterized by size of tuple

Tags: scala, tuples, implicit-conversion, scala-3

I have a type `X[D <: Int]` that I would like to convert to implicitly from a tuple.
Specifically a tuple of length `D` whose members are all `Int` should be convertable to an `X[D]`.

I am not able to write a `Conversion[A, B]` to properly perform this.

Scastie playground with my attempt

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/R3BEymtWSaqTCtDTsirTKw

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

// tuple types

type TupleAllAre[A] = [T <: Tuple] =>> T =:= TupleElementsAre[T, A]

type TupleElementsAre[T <: Tuple, A] <: Tuple = T match
   case A *: rest  => A *: TupleElementsAre[rest, A]
   case EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple

// tuple types work

val s1 = summon[TupleAllAre[Int][(Int, Int)]]
// Expected error
// val s2 = summon[TupleAllAre[Int][(Int, String, Int)]]

// target classes / methods

class X[D <: Int](x: Seq[Int]):
   def size: Int = x.size 

def definition[D <: Int](x: X[D]): Unit = ???

def def_with_conversion[T <: Tuple: TupleAllAre[Int]] (tuple: T) (using c: Conversion[T, X[Tuple.Size[T]]]): X[Tuple.Size[T]] = c(tuple)

class M[D <: Int]:
  def apply(x: X[D]): Unit = ???

val m1 = M[2]()

extension [T <: Tuple: TupleAllAre[Int]] (tuple: T)

  def ext(using c: Conversion[T, X[Tuple.Size[T]]]): X[Tuple.Size[T]] = c(tuple)

// conversion
given [T <: Tuple: TupleAllAre[Int]]: Conversion[T, X[Tuple.Size[T]]] = ???
// works with a non generic conversion
// given Conversion[(Int, Int), X[2]] = ???

// should all work

val x1: X[2] = (16, 16)

val d1 = definition[2](2, 2)
val d2: X[2] = def_with_conversion(2, 2)

val a1 = m1(2, 2)

val e1: X[2] = (2, 2).ext
```

Comment: I would still love to solve this, but i was able to go in another direction. By labeling all the methods that are supposed to take an `X`, with taking a `B` and using a `Conversion[B, X[D]]`

Comment: It's hard to see what are you trying to achieve with class X[D], creating a class that doesn't have any information in runtime. It could understand if what you want to do is more a type that refines a tuple to be of a certain size and all Int, but to create an instance of that class, mainly by implicit conversions doesn't make sense to me.
Also, some errors in the code are the parameters passed to the definition method and def_with_conversion and m1, they are not tuples, they are to parameters of type Int

Comment: i omitted the constructor and all the methods of X. will add at least a constructor

Answer (score 2):

If what you are trying to achieve is to have a type that X[D] that represent a tuple of D elements all Integer this is a way to achieve it:

```
import scala.compiletime.ops.int.*

type S = Singleton & Int

type X[D <: S] = D match
  case 0 => EmptyTuple
  case _ => Int *: X[-[D, 1]]

val x: X[2] = (1,2)

def definition[D <: S](x: X[D]): Unit = ()

val x1: X[2] = (16, 16)
println(x1)

val d1 = definition[2]((2, 2))
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/alfonsorr/pk2Avg4YToKaWtKUKxinJA

Comment: I have no problem creating the type, `[T <: Tuple: TupleAllAre[Int]]` does a similar thing as your `X[_]` (except its unsized). i am trying to create an implicit conversion to a different class `X[_]`, so i can pass tuples to methods that expect `X[_]`. Other things could potentially be converted to `X[_]` as well. I would love to avoid all the ceremony around calling `definition` as well

Comment: I *could* just use your match type `X[_]` but only if i am also able to add extension methods to it. That seems to be a problem as well. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kEuOc0gRQYS1tzKnIp7XQA

Comment: You are right, the use of tuple types generates problems in the Conversions and also extensions.

Comment: thanks for taking a swing at it, maybe ill raise it on discord / gitter